# EF 6.1 code first reverse engineering tool with mapping classes

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

When I try ef code first reverse engineering with `Entity Framework 6.1.0 Tools for Visual Studio` I get `DataAnnotation` based configurations and all the other configurations generated at `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` overridden method. They both are messy and don't look nice. I want to know has this tool a feature which will generate my mapping related configurations at separate classes which simply inherit `EntityTypeConfiguration<ModelName>`?

Comment: http://www.gembalabs.com/2014/03/20/reverse-engineer-database-custom-code-first-entity-model-mappings/